# PyAutoGui - Press key for X seconds

Tags: python, input, controls, key, pyautogui

I'm currently working on a script that presses the '**w,a,s,d**' keys in order to move a character in any game.
For this to work, i need to have the '**w**' key pressed for a specific amount of time. How can I achieve this?

I thought of something like:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('w')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.keyUp('w')
```

But this just pauses the whole program and no key is being pressed so this has no use to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As said in the doc-string from `pyautogui.keyDown()`:

> *Performs a keyboard key press without the release. This will put that
>     key in a held down state.*
>
> *NOTE: For some reason, **this does not seem to cause key repeats** like would
>       happen if a keyboard key was held down on a text field.*

---

You need a different approach - you can may use [pygame - with this](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat)

Or, if you want to stay with `pyautogui` you can try something like this:

```
def hold_W (hold_time):
    import time, pyautogui
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < hold_time:
        pyautogui.press('w')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with pyautogui.hold(key):
    pyautogui.sleep(hold)
```

This will do the trick without making your own function.