# How to create keyDown event handler?

Tags: python, keydown, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui as pag   

pag.keyDown('e')
pag.click(x=811,y=697)
pag.click(x=1277,y=508)
pag.keyUp('e')
```

Hi I am trying to press mouse button 2 times while holding the 'e' key

But `keyDown('e')` works as `press('e')`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pyautogui as pag   

pag.keyDown('e')
pag.mouseDown(x=811,y=697)
pag.mouseUp(x=1277,y=508)
pag.keyUp('e')
```

[reference](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#the-mousedown-and-mouseup-functions)

Comment: Then maybe this is the answer you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682388/pyautogui-press-key-for-x-seconds

Comment: That code repeat w several times. I want to hold down the key. btw keyDown() works on other computer. I dont know what is different :(