# pyautogui keydown and keyup arent working properly python

Tags: python, keydown, pyautogui, keyup

so I'm using pyautogui to type, and I'm trying to hold a key down for more than a second but I've ran into this problem where the key only types a single letter

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.keyDown("w")
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.keyUp("w")
```

my output is "w"
but my output should be "wwwwwwwwwwwwwww" since I'm holding down the key?

the same thing occurs when im using the press function for pyautogui,

```
pyautogui.press("w") #but instead of pressing a single key, it totally just doesnt get outputted but only works for main keyboard functions like windowsKey and enter
```

if this is wrong, is their a way i can make it so I'm holding down the key?

Comment: Similar problem in this thread from 2018: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682388/pyautogui-press-key-for-x-seconds

Answer (score 2):

From the [Documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) it seems that it's not possible to do the way you have tried, however this function can help for 'holding down' a **letter** for a set number of seconds:

```
def hold_character(hold_time, character, interval=0.1):
    pyautogui.write(character * int(hold_time / interval), interval=interval)

hold_character(2, 'w')
```

...gives the 'wwwwwwwwwwwwwww' effect for me